# ZFS settings on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nfs, zfs

im running ZFS on ubuntu 18.04 and I'm experience slow performance with NFS over 1gb ethernet. The server is a supermicro c3000, [A2SDi-8C-HLN4F](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/atom/A2SDi-8C-HLN4F.cfm). It seems that many others have/had this problem, and one of the things I have tried is to add a SSD SLOG. That didn't help much, if anything. Another thing is to set cache_flush_disable=1 on the pool. This option will not be harmful to data integrity and will still work with SLOG if I have understood correctly, but I cannot find were I set this option on the pool.

So; were/how do I set cache_flush_disable=1 on the ZFS pool on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: What exactly is *slow performance*? Reads? Writes? How did you measure it? What made you think that a SLOG will improve things?

Comment: Writes. About 70mb/sec on a 1gbit network. Have a freenas server that push 117mb/sec. I read it on internet that a SLOG might help.

Comment: Look for the `sync` setting with `zfs get sync`, as `cache_flush_disable` seems to be BSD related or outdated. Not sure. You can disable that, but that puts the data at risk and is not recommended. Also, did you export the NFS share with the `sync` option? Otherwise most writes will be `async` bypassing the SLOG. Did you test your network speed between the two computes, e.g. with iperf?

Comment: I did not export my NFS share with the `sync` option, that might be it? How would I do that? Yes I have tested with iperf and those results seems to be utilizing my network capabilities.